# Docker build not working with NextJS on node:alpine with SWC

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, next.js, alpine-linux

I have a NextJS App that I want to build into a docker image and run as a container later. I'm using the Dockerfile from https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#docker-image.

When I run `docker build .` Everything works fine until Step 10/23:

```
yarn run v1.22.15
$ next build

info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Creating an optimized production build...

Error: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /app/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu/next-swc.linux-x64-gnu.node)
```

I found out that this is caused by SWC and alpine, but does anyone know how to solve this?

Maybe this can help: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/30713

Comment: In general, if you're seeing inexplicable shared-library issues on an Alpine-based image, switching to a Debian- or Ubuntu-based image will resolve them at a relatively small space cost.  If that's not your problem, can you edit the question to include a [mcve] and not just the error message?

Answer (score 0):

`RUN rm -r node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu`

adding that und `yarn install` actually fixes that bug

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For us, some of the team members had the older versions of the npm, and that created the problem in package-lock.json.

The solution to this is to delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` from the project and run `npm install`

**Note:** If are building a docker image and your dockerfile has `COPY package*.json ./` line then the new `package-lock.json` has to be updated to the repository from where the build will happen